# Meaning of "on holiday in Spain" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, grammaticality

> I had a postcard from Joanne on holiday in Spain.  It sounds like she is having a really good time.

What do the words 'on holiday in Spain' refer to? If the second sentence is missing, what does it change the meaning?

Comment: Did you look up the words "on holiday"?  I'm not sure what your second question means.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I think it means *at the time when Joanne was spending her holidays.*

Comment: The first preposition phrase modifies *Joanne*, the second may be taken to modify either *Joanne* or *holiday* -- it amounts to pretty much the same thing.

Comment: What does it mean? It probably means that the speaker is from the UK, not the US. (In the US, the speaker would usually say, "I got a postcard from Joanne, who is on **vacation** in Spain.")

Comment: Without the second sentence, the meaning would be more ambiguous; *I* could be the one on holiday and/or in Spain.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite the sentence as:

> I **received** a postcard from Joanne, **who is** on holiday in Spain.

Although, it could also be interpreted as you receiving a postcard from Joanne while *you* were on holiday in Spain. I doubt someone would interpret it this way as you're unlikely to be receiving post while on holiday, especially since many people take short (1 to 2 week) holidays which can be shorter than the time it takes a letter (or postcard) to get to you.

If you're confused about the definition of "on holiday," here is a definition of "holiday" with example sentences (from Cambridge Dictionary):

> [**holiday**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/holiday)
>   *UK Informal: holidays, hols*
>   *US: vacation*
>
> A time when someone does not go to work or school but is free to do what
>   they want, such as travel or relax:
>
> "*a camping/skiing holiday*"
>   "*Have you decided where you're going for your holiday(s) this year?*"
>   "*Patricia is on holiday next week.*"
>   "*How many days' holiday do you get with your new job?*"
>   "*We thought we'd go to France for our summer holiday.*"
>   "*Surely the school holidays start soon.*"

Removing the second sentence doesn't change the meaning of the first.

Answer (score 0):

We often use the pronoun **on** with a noun relating to travel or to some other disruption to the routine that keeps us in the place we normally occupy:

on a trip

on a honeymoon

on a voyage

on a flight

on vacation

on holiday

on the march

on break

on furlough

on hiatus

on a jag

We are able to say things like:

> I sent a bottle of champagne to them on their honeymoon

because the word **on** conveys the idea of something *ongoing*; in other words, it is as if the preposition **on** has embedded in it the idea of **while** or **when**.

> I sent a bottle of champagne to them *while they were* on their honeymoon.

Answer (score 0):

When I say I'm on a holiday means a break from school. Or It's the holiday ( meaning Federal Holiday in which federal businesses are closed) Or It's Christmas break or Christmas Holiday. We say We are on Vacation meaning we went somewhere.